# libreria Mpdf Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php7, mpdf

Estoy tratando de realizar un PDF con dicha librería y posteriormente enviarlo por email, pero me encuentro con un problema y es que, me genera 1500 paginas en blanco, no se a que se debe las 1500  y el porque en blanco, ya que tengo una vista, a la cual le paso todos los datos desde el controlador  y me genera todo perfectamente, y tengo un boton para imprimir, que simplemente imprime el documento y otro que es para generar el PDF y enviarlo por email, al correo del usuario.... Adjunto controlador y vista a ver si alguien me puede decir que pasa. Agradezco toda ayuda de antemano.

**
@extends('layouts.app')

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <img id="logo" src="{{ asset('images/logoIntegra.png') }}" alt="" width="255" height="130">
            <br>
            <!--datosEmepresa-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pt-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    ASISTENCIA INFORMÁTICA
                </div>  
                <div class="card-body">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- FIN ROW -->
        
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 mt-5 mb-5">
            <div class="row">
                <p class="h3">Datos Cliente:</p>
            </div>
            Nombre: {{ $nombre }}
            NIF: {{ $nif }}
            Dirección: {{ $direccion }}<br/>
            Teléfono: {{ $telefono }}<br/>
            Email: {{ $email }}
            Contacto: {{ $contacto }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 mt-5 mb-5">
            <strong>DÍA:</strong>
                <span class="text">{{ $dia }}</span>
            <strong>MES:</strong>
                <span class="text">{{ $mes }}</span>
            <strong>AÑO:</strong>
                <span class="text">{{ $anno }}</span>
            <br/>
            Parte de trabajo: Nº: 180{{ $numero }}

        </div>

    </div><!-- FIN ROW -->

    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="card ancho">
            <div class="card-header">
                Diagnóstico/Trabajo a realizar:
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">
                    {{ $diagnostico }}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                        <strong>Presupuesto</strong>
                        @if($presupuesto == 1)
                            <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="presupuesto" checked>
                        @else
                            <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="presupuesto">
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                        <strong>Fecha:</strong>
                        <span class="text">{{ $fecha }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                        <strong>Conforme:</strong>
                        @if($conforme == 1)
                            <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="conforme" checked>
                        @else
                            <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="conforme">
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- FIN ROW-->
    
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="card ancho">
            <div class="card-header">
                Trabajo Realizado
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">
                    {{ $trabajoRealizado }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- FIN ROW-->

    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="card ancho">
            <div class="card-header">
                Materiales - Mano de obra y desplazamientos empleados
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Descripcion</th>
                            <th>Precio articulo</th>
                            <th>Mano de Obra</th>
                            <th>Desplazamiento</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$descripcion}}</td>
                            <td>{{$PVP}}</td>
                            <td>{{$manoObra}}€</td>
                            <td>{{$desplazamiento}}€</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- FIN ROW-->

    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="card ancho">
            <div class="card-header">
                Tipo de pago
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    @if($tipoPago == 1)
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            Contado
                            <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago1" checked="">
                        </div>
                    @else
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            Contado
                            <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago1">
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    @if($tipoPago == 2)
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            Fact. Mes 
                            <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago2" checked>
                        </div>
                    @else
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            Fact. Mes
                            <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago2">
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    @if($tipoPago == 3)
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            Bono
                            <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago3" checked>
                        </div>
                    @else
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            Bono
                            <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago3">
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- FIN ROW-->
    <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="card-header">
                Total
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Sin IVA</th>
                        <th>Con IVA 21%</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$total}}</td>
                            <td>{{$totalIva}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pb-50">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Conforme cliente: Firma/sello
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <img src="{{ asset('images/2_2020-08-17.png') }}" alt="" width="255" height="57"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div><!-- fin row -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn btn-warning ocultar" id="imprimir">Imprimir</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success ml-5 ocultar" id="enviar">
            <a href="/generarPDF/{{$cod_actuacion}}">Enviar</a>
        </button>
    </div>
```

@endsection
**

**CONTROLADOR**

```
class PdfController extends Controller{


public function getIndex(Request $request){

    // de esta manera recogemos el valo que viaja en la URL 
    $cod_actuacion = request()->cod_actuacion;

    //LLENAMOS EL PDF A PARTIR DE UNA CONSULTA CON EL CODIGO DE INCIDENCIA
    $datosIncidencia = \DB::table('incidencias')->where('cod_incidencia','LIKE','%'.$request["incidencia"]."%")->get();
    $datosSolicitante = \DB::table('usuarios')->where('cod_usuario', '=', $datosIncidencia[0]->solicitante)->get();
    $datosActuacion = \DB::table('actuacion')->where('cod_actuacion', '=',$cod_actuacion)->get();
    $materiales = \DB::table('articulo')->where('cod_articulo', '=', $datosActuacion[0]->articulo)->get();



    
    $fechaActuacion = $datosActuacion[0]->fecha;

    $nombre = $datosSolicitante[0]->nombre;
    $numero = $request["actuacion"];

    $nif = $datosSolicitante[0]->nif;
    $telefono = $datosSolicitante[0]->telefono;
    $email = $datosSolicitante[0]->email;
    $contacto = $datosIncidencia[0]->asunto;
    
    $dia = substr($datosActuacion[0]->fecha, 8, 2);
    $mes = substr($datosActuacion[0]->fecha, 4, 4);
    $anno = substr($datosActuacion[0]->fecha, 0,4);

    $direccion = $datosSolicitante[0]->direccion;
    $diagnostico = $datosIncidencia[0]->cuerpo;
    $presupuesto = "";
    $fecha = $dia.$mes.$anno;
    $conforme = $datosActuacion[0]->firma;
    $trabajoRealizado = $datosActuacion[0]->mensaje;
    $dni = "23918745";
    $total = $datosActuacion[0]->total;
    $totalIva = ($datosActuacion[0]->total * 0.21 + $datosActuacion[0]->total);
    $tipoPago = $datosSolicitante[0]->tipoPago;


    $namefile = 'Asistencia_informatica'.time().'.pdf';

    return view('pdf.generar')->with('numero', $numero)->with('datosSolicitante', $datosSolicitante)
                              ->with('datosActuacion', $datosActuacion)->with('nombre', $nombre)
                              ->with('dia', $dia)->with('mes', $mes)
                              ->with('anno', $anno)->with('nif', $nif)
                              ->with('telefono', $telefono)->with('email', $email)
                              ->with('contacto', $contacto)->with('direccion', $direccion)
                              ->with('diagnostico', $diagnostico)->with('presupuesto', $presupuesto)
                              ->with('fecha', $fecha)->with('conforme', $conforme)
                              ->with('trabajoRealizado', $trabajoRealizado)->with('total', $total)
                              ->with('totalIva', $totalIva)->with('materiales', $materiales)
                              ->with('datosActuacion', $datosActuacion)->with('tipoPago', $tipoPago)
                              ->with('descripcion', $datosActuacion[0]->mensaje)->with('PVP', $materiales[0]->PVP)
                              ->with('manoObra', $datosActuacion[0]->manoObra)->with('desplazamiento', $datosActuacion[0]->desplazamiento)
                              ->with('cod_actuacion', $cod_actuacion);
}

public function getPdf(Request $request){
    $cod_actuacion = request()->cod_actuacion;


    //LLENAMOS EL PDF A PARTIR DE UNA CONSULTA CON EL CODIGO DE INCIDENCIA
    $datosIncidencia = \DB::table('incidencias')->where('cod_incidencia','LIKE','%'.$request["incidencia"]."%")->get();
    $datosSolicitante = \DB::table('usuarios')->where('cod_usuario', '=', $datosIncidencia[0]->solicitante)->get();
    $datosActuacion = \DB::table('actuacion')->where('cod_actuacion', '=',$cod_actuacion)->get();
    $materiales = \DB::table('articulo')->where('cod_articulo', '=', $datosActuacion[0]->articulo)->get();
    
    $dia = substr($datosActuacion[0]->fecha, 8, 2);
    $mes = substr($datosActuacion[0]->fecha, 4, 4);
    $anno = substr($datosActuacion[0]->fecha, 0,4);

    $data['nombre'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->nombre;
    $data['numero'] = $cod_actuacion;;
    $data['nif'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->nif;
    $data['direccion'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->direccion;
    $data['telefono'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->telefono;
    $data['email'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->email;
    $data['contacto'] = $datosIncidencia[0]->asunto;
    $data['dia'] = $dia;
    $data['mes'] = $mes;
    $data['anno'] = $anno;
    $data['diagnostico'] = $datosActuacion[0]->mensaje;
    $data['presupuesto'] = $datosActuacion[0]->presupuesto;
    $data['fecha'] = $dia.$mes.$anno;
    $data['conforme'] = $datosActuacion[0]->conforme;
    $data['trabajoRealizado'] = $datosActuacion[0]->mensaje;
    $data['total'] = $datosActuacion[0]->total;
    $data['materiales'] = $materiales;
    $data['manoObra'] = $datosActuacion[0]->manoObra;
    $data['PVP'] = $materiales[0]->PVP;
    $data['desplazamiento'] = $datosActuacion[0]->desplazamiento;
    $data['descripcion'] = $datosActuacion[0]->mensaje;
    $data['tipoPago'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->tipoPago;

    $totalIva = ($datosActuacion[0]->total * 0.21 + $datosActuacion[0]->total);
    $tipoPago = $datosSolicitante[0]->tipoPago;

    $data['totalIva'] = $totalIva;
    $data['cod_actuacion'] = $cod_actuacion;

    $html = view('pdf.generar', $data)->render();

    $namefile = 'Asistencia_informatica'.time().'.pdf';

    $defaultConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

    $defaultFontConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];
    $mpdf = new Mpdf([
        'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
            public_path() . '/fonts',
        ]),
        'fontdata' => $fontData + [
            'arial' => [
                'R' => 'arial.ttf',
                'B' => 'arialbd.ttf',
            ],
        ],
        'default_font' => 'arial',
        // "format" => "A4",
        "format" => [264.8,188.9],
    ]);

    // $mpdf->SetTopMargin(5);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    //dd($mpdf);
    $mpdf->Output($namefile,"I");
}


public function enviarPdf(Request $request){
    $this->getPdf();

    $incidencia = $request["incidencia"];

    $datosIncidencia = \DB::table("incidencias")->where("cod_incidencia", '=', $incidencia)->get();


    $usuario = \DB::table("usuarios")->where("cod_usuario", '=', $datosIncidencia[0]->cliente)->get();

    echo var_dump($usuario[0]->email);

    //echo $email;
    exit();

    
}
```

}// FIN CLASS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para generar el PDF, la vista debe ser en **"Tablas"** aquí muestro el controlador de nuevo, he tenido que crear una nueva vista. Y también muestro la vista

**Controlador**

```
public function getPdf(Request $request){
    $cod_actuacion = request()->cod_actuacion;


    //LLENAMOS EL PDF A PARTIR DE UNA CONSULTA CON EL CODIGO DE INCIDENCIA
    $datosIncidencia = \DB::table('incidencias')- >where('cod_incidencia','LIKE','%'.$request["incidencia"]."%")->get();
    $datosSolicitante = \DB::table('usuarios')->where('cod_usuario', '=', $datosIncidencia[0]->solicitante)->get();
    $datosActuacion = \DB::table('actuacion')->where('cod_actuacion', '=',$cod_actuacion)->get();
    $materiales = \DB::table('articulo')->where('cod_articulo', '=', $datosActuacion[0]->articulo)->get();
    
    $dia = substr($datosActuacion[0]->fecha, 8, 2);
    $mes = substr($datosActuacion[0]->fecha, 4, 4);
    $anno = substr($datosActuacion[0]->fecha, 0,4);

    $data['nombre'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->nombre;
    $data['numero'] = $cod_actuacion;;
    $data['nif'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->nif;
    $data['direccion'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->direccion;
    $data['telefono'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->telefono;
    $data['email'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->email;
    $data['contacto'] = $datosIncidencia[0]->asunto;
    $data['dia'] = $dia;
    $data['mes'] = $mes;
    $data['anno'] = $anno;
    $data['diagnostico'] = $datosActuacion[0]->mensaje;
    $data['presupuesto'] = $datosActuacion[0]->presupuesto;
    $data['fecha'] = $dia.$mes.$anno;
    $data['conforme'] = $datosActuacion[0]->conforme;
    $data['trabajoRealizado'] = $datosActuacion[0]->mensaje;
    $data['total'] = $datosActuacion[0]->total;
    $data['materiales'] = $materiales;
    $data['manoObra'] = $datosActuacion[0]->manoObra;
    $data['PVP'] = $materiales[0]->PVP;
    $data['desplazamiento'] = $datosActuacion[0]->desplazamiento;
    $data['descripcion'] = $datosActuacion[0]->mensaje;
    $data['tipoPago'] = $datosSolicitante[0]->tipoPago;

    $totalIva = ($datosActuacion[0]->total * 0.21 + $datosActuacion[0]->total);
    $tipoPago = $datosSolicitante[0]->tipoPago;

    $data['totalIva'] = $totalIva;
    $data['cod_actuacion'] = $cod_actuacion;

    $html = view('pdf.genera', $data);

    $namefile = 'Asistencia_informatica'.time().'.pdf';

    $defaultConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

    $defaultFontConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];
    $mpdf = new Mpdf([
        'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
            public_path() . '/fonts',
        ]),
        'fontdata' => $fontData + [
            'arial' => [
                'R' => 'arial.ttf',
                'B' => 'arialbd.ttf',
            ],
        ],
        'default_font' => 'arial',
        // "format" => "A4",
        "format" => [264.8,188.9],
    ]);

    // $mpdf->SetTopMargin(5);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    //dd($mpdf);
    $mpdf->Output($namefile,"I");
}
```

**Vista**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>BOLETA DE VENTA</title>
            <style type="text/css">
               body{
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: "Arial";
               }
               table{
                 border-collapse: collapse;
               }
               td{
                 padding: 6px 5px;
                 font-size: 15px;
    }
    .h1{
        font-size: 21px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .h2{
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .tabla1{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .tabla2 {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .tabla3{
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .tabla3 td{
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .tabla3 .cancelado{
        border-left: 0;
        border-right: 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-top: 1px dotted #000;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .emisor{
        color: red;
    }
    .linea{
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
    }
    .border{
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .fondo{
        background-color: #dfdfdf;
    }
    .fisico{
        color: #fff;
    }
    .fisico td{
        color: #fff;
    }
    .fisico .border{
        border: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    .fisico .tabla3 td{
        border: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    .fisico .linea{
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
    }
    .fisico .emisor{
        color: #fff;
    }
    .fisico .tabla3 .cancelado{
        border-top: 1px dotted #fff;
    }
    .fisico .text{
        color: #000;
    }
    .fisico .fondo{
        background-color: #fff;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table width="100%" class="tabla1">
            <tr>
                <td width="73%" align="center">
                    <img id="logo" src="{{ asset('images/imagen.png') }}" alt="" width="255" height="130">
   <br>Datos empresa<br>
                    <br>
                  </td>
   <td width="73%" align="center">
   ASISTENCIA INFORMÁTICA
                    <br>
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">INSTALACIÓN-MANTENIMIENTO</h5>
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        PC´s / Apple / Portátiles / Servidores / Consumibles
                        Protección datos / Software / Telefonía / Video Vigilancia
                        Redes / Control de accesos / Equipos Audiovisuales
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="27%" rowspan="3" align="center" style="padding-right:0">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="50" align="center" class="border">
                                Parte de trabajo: Nº: 180 <span class="text">{{ $numero }} 
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Jr. Santander Nro. 340 Jesus María - Lima</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Telf.: (01) 364-2547 Cel.: 985-748514</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" class="tabla2">
            <tr>
                <td width="11%">Datos Cliente:</td>
                <td width="37%" class="linea">
                    <span class="text">{{ $nombre }}</span>
                </td>
                <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="13%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="7%" align="center" class="border fondo"><strong>DÍA</strong> 
                 </td>
                <td width="8%" align="center" class="border fondo"><strong>MES</strong> 
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center" class="border fondo"><strong>AÑO</strong> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dirección:</td>
                <td class="linea"><span class="text">{{ $direccion }}</span></td>
                <td>NIF:</td>
                <td class="linea"><span class="text">{{ $nif }}</span></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="center" class="border"><span class="text">{{ $dia }}</span></td>
                <td align="center" class="border"><span class="text">{{ $mes }}</span></td>
                <td align="center" class="border"><span class="text">{{ $anno }}</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" class="tabla3">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" class="fondo"><strong>Diagnóstico/Trabajo a realizar:</strong></td>
            </tr>
           
            <tr>
                <td width="7%" align="center">
                    <span class="text">{{ $diagnostico }}</p></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="59%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="16%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="18%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="border:0;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="border:0;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="right">
                    <strong>Presupuesto</strong>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    @if($presupuesto == 1)
                        <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="presupuesto" checked>
                    @else
                        <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="presupuesto">
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Fecha:</strong>
                    <span class="text">{{ $fecha }}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Conforme:</strong>
                    @if($conforme == 1)
                        <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="conforme" checked>
                    @else
                        <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="conforme">
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" class="tabla3">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Trabajo Realizado
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ $trabajoRealizado }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" class="tabla3">
            Materiales - Mano de obra y desplazamientos empleados
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Precio articulo</th>
                    <th>Mano de Obra</th>
                    <th>Desplazamiento</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$descripcion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$PVP}}</td>
                    <td>{{$manoObra}}€</td>
                    <td>{{$desplazamiento}}€</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" class="tabla3">
            Tipo de pago
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Contado</th>
                    <th>Fact.Mes</th>
                    <th>Bono</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @if($tipoPago == 1)
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                Contado
                                <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago1" checked="">
                            </div>
                        @else
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                Contado
                                <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago1">
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if($tipoPago == 2)
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                Fact. Mes 
                                <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago2" checked>
                            </div>
                        @else
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                Fact. Mes
                                <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago2">
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if($tipoPago == 3)
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                Bono
                                <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago3" checked>
                            </div>
                        @else
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                Bono
                                <input class="ml-5" type="checkbox" id="pago3">
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" class="tabla3">
             Total
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sin IVA</th>
                    <th>Con IVA 21%</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{$total}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{$totalIva}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" class="tabla3">
             Conforme cliente: Firma/sello
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firma del cliente</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/2_2020-08-17.png') }}" alt="" width="255" height="57"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```